# monitoring all outgoing information

Tags: windows-10, home-networking, monitoring, data-loss-prevention

I would like to know the best way to monitor all outgoing information / data on my computer.  I have recently set up a small office and need to assure myself that my data is safe. I need to ensure that my employees are not (1) using a data usb stick to take information nor (2) using private email (e.g. gmail) or 'wetransfer' or something similar to send information to their private accounts.  Is this possible ?

Comment: Look up _Data Loss Prevention_.

Comment: Check here for [Group Policy Removable Media](http://serverfault.com/questions/368812/restrict-access-to-certain-usb-drives) for usbs,cds and other removable storage you can deny writing or reading as well as other things. For ensuring the other issue. Using a water mark in emails as well as documents helps insure it wont be copied or sent to themselves. You could setup a rule to cc another email you use. To make sure no emails are being forwarded to private addresses. Hope this helps.

Comment: Applications such as Symantec DLP for endpoint protection. And services like WebSense for monitoring web traffic.